# How to extend log4j2 to encrypt message parameters

Tags: plugins, log4j2

I want to extend log4j2 via a plugin (or other means if necessary) so as to encrypt certain message parameters.

I've browsed through the log4j2 docs at Apache but have to admit that I'm still confused even as to what *kind* of plugin to write in order to do this.

What I'd need is access to the message parameters when they are being inserted into the actual message. My code would then examine each parameter and encrypt/hash/mask it where appropriate.

E.g. say the application developer logs something like this:

```
LOGGER.info("Account {} has a balance of {} Euros", acctNo, balance);
```

Then acctNo and balance should be passed to my plugin and I'd encrypt the account number and mask the balance. This should happen independently of whether the log goes to a file or console or whatever, i.e. independently of the appender(s) used.

Please point me to right direction... Should I write my own custom layout for this? I'd prefer to continue using log4j's layouts, such as pattern layout. I really only want to change the parameter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer here is "write your own MessageFactory" which is not strictly a plugin. Details about how to use your own MessageFactory can be found in the log4j2 docs in the "Extending log4j2" chapter.

I just did not find it very obvious from the documentation and had to browse through the Log4j2 sources to find the answer.